# Call profile edit page from Azrue B2C protected web assembly

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly, azure-ad-msal

I have created an Blazor WASM project, that is protected behind a Azure B2C Login.
So far everything is working since the template of VS2022 took care of everything.

I have set up 2 user flows in B2C

- B2C_1_signupsignin1
- B2C_1_profileediting1

Currently I am using B2C_1_signupsignin1 that takes care of the login stuff. But when I try to call the profile page I got an error that tells me that profile editing is not supported.
So far so good since this is the login user flow that is expected.
I am struggling to call the profile editing for 2 reasons

1. I did not find a way to define 2 authorities and switch between them inside the app. So that I use B2C_1_signupsignin1 for login and B2C_1_profileediting1 for profile editing.
2. I did not find any documentation on the Microsoft pages regarding profile editing using Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal

However if I exchange  B2C_1_signupsignin1 with B2C_1_profileediting1 in the appsettings I am instantly redirected to the profile editing page, so this is working at least.